# why Eclipse 4.5.2 no delta pack for download

Tags: eclipse, pack, delta

why [Eclipse 4.5.2 Release Build: 4.5.2](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.2-201602121500/#JUnitPlugin)  no delta pack for download now?

Comment: but eclipse 3.5.2(http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/winPlatform.php) have delta pack for download ,so what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Eclipse 4.5 delta packs are no longer being created.

The preferred way to do multi-platform builds is now to set your target platform to the appropriate Eclipse repository.

It is also possible to build your own delta pack. See [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse) for more details on the options. In particular note that Eclipse Tycho is now the recommended way to do builds.